# Site Hacked - Wordpress Divi Site - Cannot find where to fix the issue?

Tags: hacked

I need help trying to find out where to look to find out how to get rid of an issue on a wordpress site I manage. If you go to http://www.thedailycrave.com you will see if you scroll down to the bottom of the website right over the footer and under the map there is Red text links on two lines. It shows on all pages. When I use Google Inspector editor it shows there are like 20+ html files created from those links, one of which is here: http://thedailycrave.com/chelsea-home-football-shirts-2019.html   - yet I cannot even find where those html files are located to delete? Any help would be great! I disabled all plugins and it still shows, I already changed the wp-admin password. Have no idea how this happen or how to get things back to normal? Any help much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: i can help you with that. when did it happened?

Comment: Did you purchase the Divi theme? If you download nulled products, you are in serious risk of being hacked.

Comment: Its a lifetime licence with DIVI. after 2 years it all of a sudden happened last week

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling plugins won't help if WordPress core has been compromised (and reinstalling WordPress won't do much good if your hosting account has been compromised).

I would recommend nuking and paving your installation with help from your hosting provider (and getting a professional to audit any necessary themes and plugins you plan to use after this is completed to ensure this doesn't happen again).